# Menu click opens a small box?

Tags: android

again im having a issues, I'm trying to get when a menu item is clicked then it'll open up a box that has a title and maybe a text box/ btn in it how could I do this?

This is what menu code im using

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.icon:     Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the icon!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
        case R.id.text:     Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
        case R.id.icontext: Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the icon and text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `AlertDialog`. This [post](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) has some good examples of creating dialogs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the link :) but it doesn't show/tell me how to Incorporate it with the menu item?

Comment: @Devin, the dialog you've created has a show() method, you just need to call it on your menu item's click to see the dialog.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you Egor so late but Im still lost :(

Comment: @Devin, don't worry, I'm in Europe, it's currently day here =) Where are you lost?

Comment: :) well I have on my menu click the case R.id.icon do this, where do I put the dialog code? do I have to create a separate class with the proper dialog code in it and then some how connect it with the menu item? Im a newbie im sorry lol

Comment: @Devin, you can create a method that will initialize your dialog and call it inside onCreate() to have a dialog ready to be shown. The process of initializing the dialog is described in the link I gave you. Then you can simple call dialog.show() wherever you need it and the dialog will popup.

Comment: @Devin, You're welcome, Devin, glad I could help you. Please accept the answer, if you don't mind

Answer (score 1):

Finally figure this out with the help of Egor this is how you have it so when you click a menu item a custom dialog box appears

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.savefile:
            showDialog(SAVE_DIALOG);
    }
    return true;
}
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

    switch(id) {
    case SAVE_DIALOG:
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.savedialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Hello, this is a custom dialog!");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
        break;
    default:
        dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```